# where i can find trace for item.systemupdate()

Tags: client-object-model, splistitem, object-model, updatelistitems

I am working on a project which was initially developed by someone else. few of my list items are getting updated but i am not getting anything in version history. I believe that some schedule job is updating item.systemupdate(). 
Does sharepoint store information of item.systemupdate anywhere. I need to know who and when this item was updated (using systemupdate).

Answer (score 0):

As per official Microsoft documentation. The SystemUpdate() method updates your list item without making any changes to Modified or ModifiedBy columns. This would then also conclude that it does not create a new version. From official MS Article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx